# ¿Es posible utilizar una variable de html en la misma página en javascript o php?

Tags: javascript, html

soy nuevo en php y javascript. Tengo un problema que no he podido resolver, estoy usando un framework llamado laravel. Intento obtener un valor de un html de la siguiente línea de código:

```
<input type="number" id="replyNumber" min="0" step="1" name="edad" data-bind="value:replyNumber" />
```

Intento obtener dicho valor, entendí que php se utiliza en la parte del servidor y javascript en la parte del usuario, así que decidí utilizar javascript para obtener el resultado, de la siguiente manera:

```
var patient_age = document.getElementById("replyNumber").value;
```

Ahora en el mismo código necesito utilizar dicha variable para habilitar o deshabilitar un select bajo ciertas condiciones.El valor del patient_age lo puse en un setInterval para verificar cambios en el input.

```
<select class="custom-select"  
    
  if(condición y variable javascript)

  disabled
  
  >
```

Si cumple la variable y condición entonces deshabilita el select, hice una prueba con php pero no me funciona de manera correcta.
Agradecería su ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: No termino de entender el problema por favor explicalo mejor

Comment: Claro, tengo varios campos, la mayoría cuenta con <select> y me pidieron que mediante otro campo que es: <input type="number" id="replyNumber" min="0" step="1" name="edad" data-bind="value:replyNumber" /> obtenga su valor y conforme aumente su valor deshabilite o habilite otros campos de tipo <select>, encontré que con "disabled" lo deshabilitas e impides que el usuario eliga alguna opción, así que intente hacer como una sentencia if-else para habilitar o deshabilitar esos campos. No se si me explique bien

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!  usa el boton [edit] si necesitas hacer aclaraciones en tu pregunta...

Answer (score 1):

Respuesta usando **JQuery:**

Puedes lograr tu objetivo capturando los eventos que ese `<input>` dispare, dado que es un input tipo `number`, entonces deberías usar los eventos [`keyup`](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) y [`change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/). Así, cada vez que haya un cambio, elijas habilitar o deshabilitar elementos dependiendo del valor ingresado.

```
<input type="number" id="replyNumber" min="0" step="1" name="edad" data-bind="value:replyNumber" />

...

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#replyNumber').on('keyup change', function(e) {
      
       let valorIngresado = $(this).val();
       
       if(valorIngresado > 18){
            $("#otro-elemento-select").prop('disabled', true);
       } else {
            $("#otro-elemento-select").prop('disabled', false);
       }
    });
</script>
```

Haciendo uso de [`prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/), puedes habilitar o desahabilitar elementos html dinámicamente.

---

Respuesta usando **JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    const elementoInput = document.querySelector('#replyNumber');

    elementoInput.addEventListener('change', (event) => {

        const valorIngresado = event.target.value;

        var elementoDeshabilitar = document.querySelector("#otro-elemento-select");

        if(valorIngresado > 18){
            elementoDeshabilitar.setAttribute("disabled", "");
       } else {
            elementoDeshabilitar.removeAttribute("disabled");
       }
    });
</script>
```

Si usas Javascript, puedes ayudarte de los métodos [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) y [`removeAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) para habilitar o deshabilitar elementos.

Comment: El OP no ha especificado que use JQuery, hay que ser consistente en las respuestas. Sería bueno que indicaras que usas JQuery en tu respuesta o que incluyeras código sin JQuery. Saludos

Comment: De hecho me sirvió mucho su aportación, muchas gracias!!! aprendía algo nuevo hoy